# Deleting a zookeeper node with bad ACL

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I was experimenting with ACLs in zookeeper and accidentally created a node that has only `read` and `create` permission, but not `admin` permission. As a result (?) I cannot delete that node nor the nodes under it.

```
rmr /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000
Authentication is not valid : /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000
getAcl /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000
'world,'anyone
: cr
getAcl /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000/myOwnNote
'world,'anyone
: cdrwa
delete /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000/myOwnNote
Authentication is not valid : /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000/myOwnNote
setAcl /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000 world:anyone:cdrwa  
Authentication is not valid : /Testing/lots/Poison/todo/task-0000000000
```

Is there any way to ditch that node without throwing away the current zookeeper database?

Answer (score 0):

**Use `superDigest`**.
With the `superDigest`，you got a super user to do anything,  but have to restart your zookeeper first to make it work.
The steps to set `superDigest`, you can reference from [this article](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/29900/zookeeper-using-superdigest-to-gain-full-access-to.html) from hortonworks.